# Hard Coded Slideshow Works but Breaks When Rendered by WordPress

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have created a jQuery SlideShow that works when it's hard coded into JSFiddle (as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/t534v/7/) but breaks once it's rendered by WordPress and I can't figure out why. All the slides are within the .postContainer div, which is really the key to everything working, so I can't figure out why it's not working...

Any help would be much appreciated. I've made a JSFiddle with the rendered code from WordPress and included it here as well. Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EkVN6/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="post-container">
    <div class="post-content">
        <div class="post-meta">
            <h3>Date: May 9, 2014 | Author: Noelle Devoe | <a href="http://renegademagsu.com/?p=195/#comments"><span class="dsq-postid" rel="195 http://renegademagsu.com/?p=195">0 Comments</span></a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="post">
            <a href="http://renegademagsu.com/?p=195">
                <h1>Private: 6 Moments That Denzel Washington was a bad ass</h1>
            </a>
            <div class="slideshow">
                <div class="slideContainer">
                    <div class="slide">
                        <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://renegademagsu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/malcolm-x.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slideInfo">
                        <p class="slideCaption">
                            Denzel’s portrayal of Malcolm X was the role that most thought would win him an Oscar. In one scene, Malcolm and other members of the Nation of Islam demand the release of one of their fellow Muslims from jail by crowding the street outside of the building. After succeeding in this, Malcolm raises his hand and signals for his men to leave. With flick of his wrist, about one hundred protesters turn in unison and march away, as if a general had commanded them. Even a white cop notices his influence and says, “That’s too much power for a n***er to have.” If Malcolm X wasn’t bad ass enough, Denzel playing him just sweetened the deal.                             
                        </p>
                        <p class="slideCredit">
                            <a href="http://www.popcornreel.com/jpgimg/x%20004.png" target="_blank">
                                Popcorn Reel</a>                           
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--slideInfo end-->
                    <div class="fix"></div>
                </div>
                <!--slideContainer end-->
                <!--end if each if-->
                <div class="slideContainer">
                <div class="slide">
                <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://renegademagsu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/remember-the-titans.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="slideInfo">
                <p class="slideCaption">
                No one can forget Denzel’s role as coach of a newly integrated high school football team in 1970s Virginia. Even though this is one of Denzel’s small bad ass roles, you have to admit, Coach Boone was scary enough to intimate anyone into doing 100 push ups.                            </p>
                <p class="slideCredit">
                <a href="http://www.monologuedb.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/denzel-washington-coach-herman-boone-remember-the-titans.jpg" target="_blank">MonologueDB</a>                            </p>
                </div>
                <!--slideInfo end-->
                <div class="fix"></div>
                </div>
                <!--slideContainer end-->
                <!--end if each if-->
                <div class="slideContainer">
                    <div class="slide">
                        <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://renegademagsu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/safe-house.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slideInfo">
                        <p class="slideCaption">
                            What do you do when you’re a fugitive and a CIA agent is looking after you?  Just follow Denzel’s bad ass steps in this one scene.  After Ryan Reynolds’ character has arrested Denzel’s character, he takes him to an arena where a soccer game is taking place in order to get weapons out of a locker. While in a crowd outside the arena, Denzel manages to trick the stadium security into believing he’s being kidnapped. They not only set him free, but then arrest Ryan Reyonlds. Denzel then effortlessly waltzes right out of the stadium. No sweat for a bad ass.                            
                        </p>
                        <p class="slideCredit">
                            <a href="http://www.hbo.com/movies/safe-house" target="_blank">HBO</a>                            
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--slideInfo end-->
                    <div class="fix"></div>
                </div>
                <!--slideContainer end-->
                <!--end if each if-->
                <div class="slideContainer">
                    <div class="slide">
                        <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://renegademagsu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/training-day.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slideInfo">
                        <p class="slideCaption">
                            Who could forget Denzel’s Academy Award winning role as Detective Alonzo Harris, the corrupt and rogue narcotics officer who plays by his own rules.  A memorable scene is when Alonzo and the rookie cop Jake, stop two guys from raping a 14-year-old girl. While Jake chooses to arrest them, Alonzo grabs one of the men, puts a knife to his throat, and then points 2 guns at his crouch, threatening to shoot him.  Instead of shooting he punches him and says, “Man I’m thirsty, I could use a beer.”                              
                        </p>
                        <p class="slideCredit">
                            <a href="http://roley.tumblr.com/post/8472254874/told-me-to-suck-your-dick-is-that-what-you" target="_blank">
                                roley.tumblr.com   </a>                         
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--slideInfo end-->
                    <div class="fix"></div>
                </div>
                <!--slideContainer end-->
                <!--end if each if-->
                <div class="slideContainer">
                <div class="slide">
                <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://renegademagsu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/man-on-fire.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="slideInfo">
                <p class="slideCaption">
                If you want to learn about revenge, just watch Denzel in action in this movie after kidnappers try to take little Dakota Fanning. Denzel, her bodyguard, gets ahold of a corrupt cop who he needs answers from, and interrogates him by sticking a detonator up his rectum, threatening to blow the cop up if he doesn’t get information. However, when he finally gets the answers he’s looking for, Denzel detonates the bomb anyway and walks away from the explosion in slow motion. Total bad ass move.                             </p>
                <p class="slideCredit">
                <a href="http://www.thefancarpet.com/uploaded_assets/images/gallery/1498/Man_On_Fire_18347_Medium.jpg" target="_blank">The Fan Carpet</a>                            </p>
                </div>
                <!--slideInfo end-->
                <div class="fix"></div>
                </div>
                <!--slideContainer end-->
                <!--end if each if-->
                <div class="slideContainer">
                    <div class="slide">
                        <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://renegademagsu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/american-gangster.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slideInfo">
                        <p class="slideCaption">
                            Denzel plays the notorious gangster, Frank Lucas, who kills a man who doesn’t pay him the money he owes.  Without hesitation, Lucas kills the man in the street in broad daylight with people around. As if that wasn’t badass enough, right after, he returns to the restaurant he’d been in, and continues eating his food, as if nothing had happened.  Now that’s bad ass.                              
                        </p>
                        <p class="slideCredit">
                            <a href="http://www.dvdbeaver.com/film2/DVDReviews42/american%20gangster%20blu-ray/HF7Y9005_american_gangster_blu-ray.jpg" target="_blank">DVD Beaver</a>                            
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--slideInfo end-->
                    <div class="fix"></div>
                </div>
                <!--slideContainer end-->
                <!--end if each if-->
                <!--end each-->
            </div>
            <!--slideshow end-->
            <div class="slideNav">
                <div class="prevSlide">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="slideCount"></div>
                <div class="nextSlide">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="fix"></div>
            </div>
            <!--end if-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
     background-color: #000;
     font-family:'Source Sans Pro', Arial;
     font-size: 18px;
 }

b, strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}

 .container {
     width: 960px;
     margin: 0 auto;
 }

 header {
     width: 100%;
     height: 135px;
 }

 .logo {
     width: 260px;
     height: 135px;
     float: left;
 }

 nav {
     width: 685px;
     height: 135px;
     padding-left:15px;
     float: left;
 }

 nav ul li {
     float: left;
     line-height: 135px;
     position: relative;
 }

 nav ul li a {
     font-size: 24px;
     color: white;
     background-color: black;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-right: 20px;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     display: block;
 }

 nav ul li a:hover {
     text-decoration: underline;
 }

 nav ul ul {
     width: 200px;
     height: 50px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 85px;
     left: 0;
     display: none;
     z-index: 1000;
 }

 nav ul ul li {
     float: none;
     line-height: 50px;
 }

 nav ul ul li a {
     font-weight: regular;
     font-size: 20px;
 }

 nav ul li:hover ul {
     display: block;
 }

 .search {
     width: 260px;
     height: 135px;
     float: left;
 }

 section {
     width: 640px;
     float: left;
 }

 .post-container {
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     margin-bottom: 30px;
 }

 .post-image img {
     max-width: 100%;
     z-index: 1;
 }

 .post-content {
     position: relative;
     left: 30px;
     width: 580px;
     z-index: 2;
 }

 .thumbnail-positioning {
     bottom: 110px;
     margin-bottom: -110px;
 }

 .post-content p {
     line-height: 22px;
     margin-bottom: 15px;
 }

 .post-content img {
     max-width: 100%;
 }
 .post-meta h3 {
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-size: 12px;
     color: white;
     margin-bottom: 3px;
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 }
 .post-meta a {
     color: white;
     text-decoration: underline;
     font-weight: bold;
 }

 .post {
     background-color: white;
     color: black;
     padding: 15px;
 }

 .post ol {
     list-style-type: none;
     list-style-type: decimal !ie;
     /*IE 7- hack*/
     margin: 0;
     margin-left: 3em;
     padding: 0;
     counter-reset: li-counter;
 }

 .post ol > li {
     position: relative;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     padding-left: 0.5em;
     min-height: 3em;
     border-left: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
 }

 .post ol > li:before {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: -1em;
     width: 0.8em;
     font-size: 3em;
     line-height: 1;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: right;
     color: #464646;
     content: counter(li-counter);
     counter-increment: li-counter;
 }

 .post p:last-child {
     margin-bottom: 0 !important;
 }

 .post h1 {
     font-size: 34px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-bottom: 7px;
 }

 .post a {
     color: black;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

 .page {
     width: 550px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     background-color: white;
     padding: 15px;
 }

 .page p {
     line-height: 22px;
     margin-bottom: 15px;
 }

 .page h1 {
     font-size: 34px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: bold;
     border-bottom: 1px solid black;
     margin-bottom: 7px;
 }

 .leftimage {
     margin: 0 10px 2px -50px;
     float: left;
 }

 .leftcaption {
     margin: 3px 0 0 80px;
     font-style: italic;
     font-size: 11px;
     width: 220px;
 }

 .leftimage img {
     max-width: 300px;
 }

 .rightimage {
     margin: 0 -50px 2px 10px;
     float: right;
 }

 .rightcaption {
     margin: 3px 80px 0 0;
     font-style: italic;
     font-size: 11px;
     width: 220px;
 }

 .rightimage img {
     max-width: 300px;
 }

 aside {
     width: 290px;
     float: right;
 }

 aside h1 {
     color: white;
     font-size: 28px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid white;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 aside .widget {
     margin-bottom: 20px;
 }

 aside ul li {
     margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 aside ul li a {
     font-size: 19px;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

 aside ul li a:hover {
     font-size: 19px;
     color: black;
     background-color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

input[type=text]{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    color:#505358;
    font-size: 18px;
}

 footer {
     width: 100%;
 }

 footer .widget {
     width: 300px;
     float: left;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     padding-right: 20px;
 }

 footer h1 {
     color: white;
     font-size: 28px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid white;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 footer ul li a {
     font-size: 19px;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

 footer ul li a:hover {
     font-size: 19px;
     color: black;
     background-color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

 .alignleft {
     float: left;
     margin: 0 10px 2px -45px;
 }

 .alignright {
     float: right;
     margin: 0 -45px 2px 10px;
 }

 .fix {
     clear: both;
 }

/************SLIDESHOW************/

.slideshow {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
.slideContainer {
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
.slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.slideMiddle {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.slide img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.slideInfo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
.slideNav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
.prevSlide {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: left;
}
.nextSlide {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
.slideCount {
    width: 23.3%;
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    left:40%;
}
.slideCredit {
    width: 100%;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
  $('.slideCount').each(function(){
    var text='1/'+$(this).parents('div.postContainer').find('.slideContainer').length
    $(this).text(text)
    })
  $(".slideshow").height($(".slideContainer").height());    
  $('.nextSlide').show()  
  $('.prevSlide').hide()

    $('div.nextSlide').click(function (e){
    var count=parseInt($(this).siblings('.slideCount').text())
    var slideshow=$(this).parents('div.postContainer').find('.slideshow')
    var slides = $(slideshow).children().length;
    if(count===slides){
      e.preventDefault()
        }else{
      count++
      $(this).parents('div.postContainer').find('div.slideContainer:first').appendTo(slideshow) 
      $(this).siblings('.slideCount').text(count+'/'+slides)
    }
    if(count===slides){$(this).hide()}else{$(this).parent().find('div.prevSlide').show()}
    });

    $('.prevSlide').click(function (e){
    var count=parseInt($(this).siblings('.slideCount').text().slice(0,-2))
    var slideshow=$(this).parents('div.postContainer').find('.slideshow')
    var slides = $(slideshow).children().length;
    if(count===1){e.preventDefault()}else{
      count--
      $(this).parents('div.postContainer').find('div.slideContainer:last').prependTo(slideshow) 
      $(this).siblings('.slideCount').text(count+'/'+slides)
    } 
    if(count===1){$(this).hide()}else{$(this).parent().find('div.nextSlide').show()} 
    });
```

Comment: You need to find out what causes the collision. In Chrome or Firefox, right click anywhere on your wordpress page, select "Inspect element", then when it opens select "Console" tab, then reload your page, and see if any errors show up. Share them here. You can do similar thing with other browsers as well.

Comment: @Freelancer Thanks for your response. I just checked the console in Chrome - it doesn't have any errors listed.

Comment: Ok, so that's good. In which way exactly does the slideshow break in wordpress?

Comment: @Freelancer The same way it does on this JSFiddle (it includes the rendered code from my wordpress blog): http://jsfiddle.net/EkVN6/ So it renders all the slides and places them on top of one another - its just the code that handles changing the slides isn't working, which makes me think it has something to do with my HTML. I just can't find the error.

Comment: Is the code 100% identical on both fiddles? If there's any difference, even small, maybe that's where to look for.

Comment: is it anything to do with the `slideCount` class not existing in ur html

Comment: @gardni Thanks for your response. postCount is there on line 119.

Comment: @Freelancer Yes, it turned out that because the immediate parent in the WordPress code was .post and not .postContainer, that's what was tripping up the jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.postContainer` is set as `post-container` in your html for the broken fiddle